# Get rid of "warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input"

Tags: bash

I'm getting `-bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input` when I run `model=$(cat /proc/device-tree/model)`

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)
```

With bash version 4.3.30 it's all OK

I understand the problem is the terminating `\0` character in the file, but how can I suppress this stupid message? My whole script is messed up since I'm on bash 4.4

Comment: As an aside, `var=$(cat somefile)` is more efficiently written `var=$(<somefile)`; this latter invocation avoids both forking a subshell and executing an external command (`/bin/cat`).

Comment: ...I need to correct myself there: While it's *possible* to avoid forking in this case (ksh does, for example!), in bash through 4.4 -- and potentially forward, until someone submits a patch -- this avoids only the `exec`, not the `fork()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Does that only apply to `cat`, or would it work with `find`?

Comment: @HashimAziz, it's specifically a built-in replacement for `cat`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two possible behaviors you might want here:

- Read until first NUL. This is the more performant approach, as it requires no external processes to the shell. Checking whether the destination variable is non-empty after a failure ensures a successful exit status in the case where content is read but no NUL exists in input (which would otherwise result in a nonzero exit status).

  ```
  IFS= read -r -d '' model </proc/device-tree/model || [[ $model ]]
  ```
- Read ignoring all NULs. This gets you equivalent behavior to the newer (4.4) release of bash.

  ```
  model=$(tr -d '\0' </proc/device-tree/model)
  ```

  You could also implement it using only builtins as follows:

  ```
  model=""
  while IFS= read -r -d '' substring || [[ $substring ]]; do
    model+="$substring"
  done </proc/device-tree/model
  ```

Comment: I prefer this one: `model=$(tr -d '\0' </proc/device-tree/model)` - I don't get the `|| [[ $model ]]` syntax in the first and last examples

Comment: @SBF, that syntax ensures that the command returns `true` if read successfully read anything, even if it *didn't* find a NUL delimiter at the end. That works because `[[ $foo ]]` acts the same as `[ -n "$foo" ]`, checking if the value is non-empty -- so the `while` condition is true if either `read` returned true (meaning it found a NUL), *or* if the variable is non-empty after `read` is done.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: What if you actually want to preserve the NUL byte?

Comment: @SimonShine, you *can't* store a NUL byte in a string variable in bash (without using base64 encoding, uuencoding, or some other means of making those NULs *no longer be NULs*); they're C strings, which means they're NUL-terminated.

Comment: @SimonShine, ...now, you could read your stream into an *array*, with the separation between elements aligning with the locations of NULs, but that's the closest you can get.

Comment: @SimonShine, ...tracking whether the *last* element of the array refers to content that was NUL-terminated gets a little tricky, if you need to precisely reproduce input where it could have gone either way; not sure if I've written an answer on how to do it here before -- if you can't find one, feel free to ask a new question on the subject and @ me in.

Answer (score 45):

If you just want to delete the null byte:

```
model=$(tr -d '\0' < /proc/device-tree/model)
```