# Get rid of “warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input”

Tags: bash, shell

I recently upgraded bash, now I get this error opening a new terminal:

```
-bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

this is the line in my .bash_profile causing the issue:

`PS1="\[ $txtblu\w$txtgrn\$(branch)$txtwht ∴$txtrst \]"`

NB Bash Version

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0)
```

What do I need to change to remove this warning?

Variables:

```
txtrst='\[\e[0m\]'    # Text Reset
txtblu='\[\e[0;34m\]' # Blue
txtgrn='\[\e[0;32m\]' # Green
txtwht='\[\e[0;37m\]' # White
txtred='\[\e[0;31m\]' # Red
```

Comment: What are the 3 dots before `$txtrst`? Please show also how the variables are set.

Comment: Is `branch` outputting a nul byte? If so, make it not do that.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163678/get-rid-of-warning-command-substitution-ignored-null-byte-in-input

Comment: OK I solved it by updating to
`\n\e[0;31m\ ` from  `\n\e[\0;31m\ `