# line 17: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Tags: bash

I am a beginner with Bash script and I have a doubt with an error in my code.

```
cari.sh: line 17: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

Code at line: 17 is

```
GET=$(curl --silent --max-time 10 --connect-timeout 10 -L "${Website}")
```

I got the error when I used Looping and with Multithread like this :

```
IFS=$'\r\n'
n=1
t=3
for Website in $(cat $WEB); do
        f=$(expr $n % $t)
        if [[ $f == 0 && $n > 0 ]]; then
                sleep 1
        fi
        RUN $TARGET $n &
        n=$[$n+1]
done
wait
```

I am using `2 > /dev/null`  when running the script. I got the same error .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163678/get-rid-of-warning-command-substitution-ignored-null-byte-in-input

Comment: pipe it through `tr -d '\0'` before assign to var

Comment: GET=$(curl --silent --max-time 10 --connect-timeout 10 -L "${Website}" | tr -d '\0') Like this ? @alecxs

Comment: What is the content you get from `${Website}`? If it's binary (an image, or something like that), removing nulls will damage it. Shell variables are not suitable for storing binary data. If it's text-like with nulls mixed in, then removing them with `tr -d '\0'` may solve it (although I'd really like to know what nulls are doing there in the first place -- they shouldn't be there in text-like data) (well, unless it's something like UTF-16 format, in which case it's essentially binary).

Answer (score 0):

curl will output more in the script than it would on the command line when silent is enabled apparently(?!). I came across the same problem when simply trying to check if a webserver is reachable:

Even though `curl --max-time 5 --silent --write-out '%{response_code}' $hostname` only prints "200" when executed directly in a terminal, it spews the whole payload data when it runs in a script possibly leading to the error of the OP. My fix is to simply tell curl to output to `/dev/null`. This makes it drop the payload data while still printing the response code normally to stdout(!?!?), thus:

`curl --max-time 5 --silent --write-out '%{response_code}' -o /dev/null $hostname`

curl is great but some behavior is not exactly intuitive even after reading the documentation IMHO.