# Why isn't echo printing the output of $(grep ... /proc/net/bonding/bond0)?

Tags: bash, output, echo

When I run a `grep` pipeline directly I get two lines of output:

```
$ grep Interface /proc/net/bonding/bond0 | cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/ //g'
eno1np0
eno2np1
$
```

Strangely, the output is empty when I capture it and call `echo`:

```
$ echo $(grep Interface /proc/net/bonding/bond0 | cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/ //g')
              
$
```

A `for` loop through grep's output shows many empty lines:

```
$ for a in $(grep Interface /proc/net/bonding/bond0 | cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/ //g'); do echo $a; done
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
$
```

For what it's worth, I have tried redirecting stderr to stdout with no luck:

```
echo $(grep Interface /proc/net/bonding/bond0 2>&1 | cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/ //g')
```

I even tried using `cat` instead of `grep`.

How can I get `echo` to actually print what's being output by the `grep` command? Normally, `echo` works. I can echo output just I like normally would, for other things. I can echo text into a file. I just can't get it to work with this `grep` pipeline.

Comment: Drop the backslashes before double quotes.

Comment: The backslashes there are just to demonstrate that it's only outputting spaces. The quotes do not actually do anything to change the output

Comment: Instead of using a `/proc` device, which can have different content every time it's read, can you reproduce this with input coming from a real file? That way people who aren't you (and don't have your specific network configuration) have some chance of reproducing this themselves.

Comment: BTW, while it's not relevant to the specific problem you're encountering, the advice in [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) generally applies.

Comment: [bash warning: command substitution ignored null byte in input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64550414/bash-warning-command-substitution-ignored-null-byte-in-input) is a question about how newer versions of bash deal with this same problem.

Comment: providing the output of `xxd /proc/net/bonding/bond0` could help

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well, you can revert the hexdump with `xxd -r`; IMO the advantage  of `xxd` over `base64` would be that you get something "meaningful/readable" directly in the question.

Comment: @Fravadona, nice, thank you -- I wasn't aware `xxd -r` existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My hunch is that the results from `/proc/net` actually contain null bytes, which throw off the shell.

What you are trying is quite similar to the infamous [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) though I suppose if the goal is to get all the output on a single line, it's not entirely useless (but still broken, because the shell will expand any wildcards in the results).

Perhaps try this:

```
grep Interface /proc/net/bonding/bond0 |
tr '\000' '\012' |
sed 's/^[^:]*://;s/ //g;N;s/^[^:]*://;s/ //g;s/\n/ /'
```

though the `s/\n/ /` thing is probably not portable to all `sed` variants.

Comment: More modern bash releases ignore NUL bytes in command substitution output, but I have no idea which version RockyLinux 8 uses; it could well be old enough to silently truncate.

Comment: @tripleee that almost worked, except the output is a little incorrect (`eno1np0 SlaveInterface:eno2np1`). I can figure out what I need to change, though. I'll look at the link in your answer, thanks. I'm decently in bash, but this one is new to me

Comment: I updated to do another `s/^[^:]*://` before the `N`

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out, based on information from @CharlesDuffy and @tripleee, and a colleague of mine.

I am not sure it's a common occurrence, but posting here in case someone else runs into this in the future.

The cause was that the environment variable `IFS` was set to a non-standard character. While `cat` and `grep` were working correctly - presumably because neither depends on `IFS` to work - `echo` was not.

I am not entirely sure how this happened, but for anyone that faces this issue, check your environment for a variable named `IFS` (`env | grep IFS`), and set it back to the default (`' \t\n'`).

PS: bad start to a mid-week morning /facepalm

Comment: Lack of quoting strikes again. First rule of bash, always quote expansions: `echo "$(grep Interface /proc/net/bonding/bond0 | cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/ //g')"`. Unquoted expansions are subject to word splitting, which is what burned you here.

Comment: Second rule of bash, don't change `IFS` globally. When you do need to change it, prepend it to the command that needs it so it's only set temporarily for that one command. For example, `IFS=',' read a b c` is a safe way to read comma-separated fields as `IFS=','` doesn't persist past that single `read` command.

Comment: Or if you need it to last for longer, use a subshell, like `foo; (IFS=','; bar; baz); quux`. `IFS=','` affects `bar` and `baz` but not `quux`.

Comment: You may see old school scripts do `OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=','; bar; baz; IFS=$OLDIFS`, saving and restoring `IFS`. It's a unsophisticated trick. The other two ways are more elegant and more foolproof.

Comment: To be clear, it's not `echo` itself that looks at IFS, but the shell's process of assembling a command line from an unquoted expansion. That process is identical for `grep` or `cat` as well, the reason they weren't burned is that you were passing them filenames instead of content.

Comment: BTW, to return IFS to defaults, run `IFS=$' \t\n'` -- the default is a three-character sequence, rather than the unset state. (The unset state acts a lot like the default, but it's not quite identical; in particular, it can lead to surprises from programs that try to manage IFS's value explicitly).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy - updated to set to default, rather than unset, based on your comment