# Grep: Issue with null byte

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sh

I have the following command in a bash script.

```
GREP_RESULT=$(grep -zoP "\.global LIST(.|\n)*-1\Z" part1.s)
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

I have tried the solution proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163678/get-rid-of-warning-command-substitution-ignored-null-byte-in-input) post, changing it to the following.

```
GREP_RESULT=$(tr -d '\0' < grep -zoP "\.global LIST(.|\n)*-1\Z" part1.s)
```

This in turn results to the following error.

```
grep: No such file or directory
```

What is the proper way to work around the first error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Comment from OP: `grep -z` is adding a `\0` on end of stream

So, this *is* a case of needing to modify the `grep` output (as opposed to modifying the input file):

```
grep -zoP "\.global LIST(.|\n)*-1\Z" part1.s | tr -d '\0'
```

---

Original answer ...

Apply the `tr` to the data file first; a couple variations:

```
grep -zoP "\.global LIST(.|\n)*-1\Z" <(tr -d '\0' < part1.s)

# or 

tr -d '\0' < part1.s | grep -zoP "\.global LIST(.|\n)*-1\Z"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error with both approaches. When I test them in the terminal on their own, they work fine. It's assigning their output to the GREP_RESULTS variable that causes the null byte error.

Comment: The issue was that the output of grep with the -z option had a null byte at the end, not the file. So doing `GREP_RESULT=$(grep -zoP "\.global LIST(.|\n)*-1\Z" part1.s | tr -d '\0')` works.